# how two column page with form and table css to work in mobile

Tags: php, html, css, forms

After more than a month of coding I though I'm already finish it that's why I put it on hosting already, but after I check it on my mobile phone it shock me of the result :(

This is the result in mobile

[Form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQW0l.jpg)

[Form image with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgPZs.jpg)

anyone can give me an idea on what should I do? i dont want to make from scratch again this is my css, this is two column in 1 page with form in the left and table in the right

```
body {
        
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}  
      
      
h3 {
    
      position:relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 2;
      }

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
        
}

.left {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1 2px 5px #f5f5f5; 
  background: white; 
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}

.right {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1 2px 5px #f5f5f5; 
  background: white; 
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}


.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input[type="text"]
{ 
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 12px; line-height: 5px; 
margin: 5px;
height: 40px;
}

  label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;

        padding-left: 5px
      }

  .main-block {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-color: #85C1E9;
      
      }
 .btn-block {
      margin-top: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
  button {
    outline: none;
      font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;     
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px; 
      background: #00BFFF;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #fff;  
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      button:hover {
      background: cyan;
      } 
.msg {
    margin: 30px auto; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #3c763d; 
    background: #dff0d8; 
    border: 1px solid #3c763d;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.mix3 {
     margin: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     border-width: strong;
     padding: 10px 10px;;    

     
}
```

This is the form

```
      
<div class="main-block">
<div class="column left">
<a href="pv-form"  title="Open Fullscreen PV Form" style="font-size:24px; color:black; float:right;" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-window-restore"></i></a>
<div class="mix3">  
<h5 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:-10px"><b style="color:red"> STATUS:<a style="color:blue"> <?php echo $status; ?></a></b></h5> 
</div>  
<form name="frmUser" method="post">
<div><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
</div>
<div >
<h3><b>Payment Voucher Form </b></h3>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:20px; " class="bootstrap-demo">
<label style="margin-left: 20px;  font-weight: bold;" class="checkbox-inline"> <!-- class checkbox-inline to display checkbox inline -->
   <!-- input type checkbox -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="cashbox" value="Cash"> Cash
</label>

<label style="margin-left: -50px;  font-weight: bold;" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chequebox" value="Cheque"> Cheque 
</label>
<label style="margin-left: -50px; margin-right: -30px;  font-weight: bold;" class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="banktransferbox" value="BankTransfer"> Bank Transfer
</label>
 </div>

<input type="hidden" name="userid"  class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
<div class="form-row">
<input type="hidden" name="id" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
<div class="col-md-7 mb-2">
<label>Payment Voucher ID</label>
<input placeholder="Payment Voucher ID" id ="pv_no" type="text" name="pvid" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['PViD']; ?>">
</div> 
<div class="col-md-5 mb-2">
<label>Date</label>
<input placeholder="Date" type="text" id="pvdate" name="pvdate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['PVDate']; ?>">
</div> 
<div class="col-md-7 mb-2">
<label>Paid to</label>
<input placeholder="Paid to" type="text" name="pvname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 mb-2">
<label>Contact No.</label>
<input placeholder="Contact #" type="text" name="contactnumber" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ContactNumber']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="mb-2" style="padding-left: 20px">
<label>The Sum of</label>
<textarea placeholder="The Sum of"  name="suminwords" class="form-control"><?php echo $row['SumInWords']; ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="mb-2" style="padding-left: 20px">
<label>In Respect of</label>
<textarea placeholder="Respectof"  name="respectof" class="form-control"><?php echo $row['RespectOf']; ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<label>Price</label>
<input placeholder="Total" type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Price']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" >
<label>Cash</label>
<input placeholder="Cash" type="text" name="cash" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Cash']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" style="float:right">
<label>Bank Name</label>
<input placeholder="Bank Name" type="text" name="bankname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['BankName']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<label>VAT 5%</label>
<input placeholder="VAT" type="text" name="vat" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['VAT']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<label>Total</label>
<input placeholder="Total" type="text" name="total" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['Total']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2">
<label>Cheque No</label>
<input placeholder="Cheque No" type="text" name="chequenumber" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ChequeNumber']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" style="float:right">
<label>Cheque Date</label>
<input placeholder="Cheque Date" type="text" id="cheque_date" name="chequedate" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ChequeDate']; ?>">
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom: 150px"> </div>
<label class="col-md-8">&nbsp; Remarks</label>
<div class="mb-2" style="padding-left: 20px">
<textarea placeholder="Remarks"  name="remarks" class="form-control"><?php echo $row['Remarks']; ?></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" style="float:right">
<label>Prepared By </label>
<input placeholder="Cheque No." type="text" name="preparedby" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['PreparedBy']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" style="float:right">
<label>Approved By </label>
<input placeholder="Cheque No." type="text" name="approvedby" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ApprovedBy']; ?>">
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-2" style="float:right">
<label>Received By </label>
<input placeholder="Received By" type="text" name="receivedby" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ReceivedBy']; ?>">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 mb-1">
 <div class="btn-block">
<button style="width:40%; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); color:black; margin-left: 20px" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><b>Update / Add Record</b></button>

</div>

</div>

</form>
<button onclick="location.href='/payment-voucher'" type="button" style="width:30%; color:white; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); background-color:red; font-size: 15px; float:right; padding: 15px;"><b>Clear</b></button>
</div>      

                <div class="column right">
<a href="pv-records"  title="Open Fullscreen PV Records" style="font-size:24px; color:black; float:right" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-window-restore"></i></a>              
<div>
<h3><b>Payment Voucher List </b></h3>
</div>              
                <div class="col-md-6">  
                     <input size="50" type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name.." />  
                </div> 
                <br><br><br>        
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
                </div>                              
                <div class="col-md-5">  
                     <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />  
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
                <br>  
                <div id="pvoucher">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr style="background-color: #85C1E9; color:white; ">    
                               <th>ID</th>
                                <th>PVID</th>
                                <th>PVDate</th>  
                                <th>Name</th>                                   
                                <th>Update</th>  
                                <th>Delete</th>  
                                <th>Print</th>
        
                          </tr>  
                    
                     </table>  
                        
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])):                     
                        $e = $_SESSION['message'];                      
                        ?>
                        <div class="msg">
                        <?php 
                        
                        $e = $_SESSION['message'];  
                        echo '<tr>';  
                        echo '<td colspan="5">'. $e . '</td>';  
                        echo    '</tr>';        
                        unset($_SESSION['message']);
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif 
                        ?>
                        
                </div>  
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@media` and for example when width of window is smaller than 700px set one column. You should also add `meta` tag to your html to give browser tips how should scal your website on mobile phones.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: i dont know if what i understand is correct, if  I use @media do i need two different css for pc and mobile? then my css now will be double it that correct?

Comment: No. You just set css for pc/mobile and then you can just some of properties change to different value or add new properties depending on width